# QGIS Offline Editing Plugin: Automate manual steps to sync offline database with cloud database

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, offline

The Offline Editing Plugin offers a good way to work offline on a project and sync it later with a cloud database. The problem is that before I go offline I need to explicitly do some manual steps to convert the project to an offline project. That means if I'm already offline I can't start offline editing.

How could I solve this problem? My first idea was to automate this process and whenever I sync the project back with the cloud database I directly convert it back to an offline project.

Even better would be if QGIS detects if I have a connection to the cloud. And if so I can work directly on the cloud database. And if I have no connection It will save it in the offline project an as soon as it has a connection to the cloud it will sync it automatically.

Does anyone have experiences with a similar use case? Or any advice on how to solve this problem the best?